# Open URL or PDFreader in custom screen Android

Tags: android, pdf, window

I am working on application where I need to open inbuilt apps in a custom screen like in Popup window 
but when I invoke the inbuilt app the screen size is full screen while I need customize screen size. The inbuilt app can be anything like browser or pdfreader.

Here is my code :-

```
String strurl = "/sdcard/download/28889.pdf"; 

     File file = new File(strurl); 

     if (file.exists()) { 
         Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); 
      //   Log.e("path of the file",path.toString()); 
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 

         intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); 
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 



         try { 
             startActivity(intent); 
         }  
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  
                 "No Application Available to View PDF",  
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
         }
```

This opens up new window in my app but I need Popup kind of window where I need to show this pdfreader to get display.

Comment: Sorry.. Its not possible.. using any third party native app. Build your own pdf reader and make activity theme as Dialog.. All d Best..!

Comment: Above comment is the only possible way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, Android does not allow one app to run inside another (among other things, for obvious security reasons). So if that is what you want to do, you are out of luck.

BUT you can use a WebView (I let you consult the doc on this class) to display a webpage inside your app.
There are also some pdf libraries out there. A word of caution though, I worked on a pdf reader on Android 1 year ago and implementing a pdf reader was just not the best solution. Handling the pdf decoding on server side and serving a view of this image (or conversion to html) was the best solution.
This way you don't use too much computing power to read the pdf (surprisingly you need some serious cpu to read a pdf).

Things may have changed since I made that development (I was really constrained by the time factor) though but I still don't think that unless you explicitely need to display a pdf document and not just a document (for example a legitimate reason would be that you need to check the signature of the pdf on the Android device), you should not use the pdf format on a phone.

Comment: oh is that the case? if you have worked on pdfreader then could you please tell me If I can open a Pdf in a webview and pdf is located on SD card.    WebView mWebView=new WebView(PdftestActivity.this); mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); String linkto = "/sdcard/download/song.pdf"; mWebView.loadUrl("docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+linkto); setContentView(mWebView);

Comment: I think there is a misconception here : as far as I know, neither the stock browser, nor Chrome for Android support pdfs. No need in fact, since there are tons of pdf readers on Android & that one is shipped with each terminal.
So you can make your webview point on a pdf if you want to but it won't wield any interesting result.
You can however use the dirty trick that is pointing to http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.abc.com/xxxxxyyyyyxz.pdf" . This will work but you need to have your pdf on a webpage somewhere.

Comment: There are some open source pdf libraries, if you really want to read a pdf on Android, that is the way to go.
But again, I don't know what you are trying to do, but unless you absolutely need to read pdfs, I would advise you not to.
This format is just not adapted to mobile at all.

Answer (score 0):

For web URL You can use Webview

For PDF

You need to make your pdf reader or you can use any open source  pdf reader  to make your own customized version of the pdf reader which you can use in your app.

Some of the them are

1) http://www.mupdf.com/

2) http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/

3) Search on  Google/SO for other Links

Comment: The same question I want to ask you that I have asked abovr If I can open a Pdf in a webview and pdf is located on SD card. WebView mWebView=new WebView(PdftestActivity.this); mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); String linkto = "/sdcard/download/song.pdf"; mWebView.loadUrl("docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+linkto); setContentView(mWebView);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Example code for pdf Reader:

http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-pdf-reader.html